# Place Tab Activity at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, xml

Hi guys how can I position the acitvity tab at the bottom of the screen? below I have inserted xml of the activity. When I create an activity tab to be inserted it is always inserted at the top! When I create an activity tab to be inserted it is always inserted at the top

**Tab Image:**

[image]

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".View.TabActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/home"
                android:text="Home" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/articoli"
                android:text="Articoli" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/rapportini"
                android:text="Rapportini" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use BottomNavigationView instead of tab view and link your view pager to this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

```
layout resource file:
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />

 res/menu/my_navigation_items.xml:
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/menu_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />
     <item android:id="@+id/action_navigation"
          android:title="@string/menu_navigation"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu" />
 </menu>
```